# Ocean SDK Academic license

Tags: ocean, petrel

I'm currently studying at HW university, and the topic of my individual project (diploma research) is to develop a petrel plug-in by ocean framework. The aim of that project is to "automatically" locate and configure horizontal wells in particular way. But unfortunately to use ocean sdk a specialized license is needed. Our university has got petrel runtime license, but not the "developer" license. Is it possible to obtain some kind of academic license as it happens for microsoft products at dreamspark ? May be just for some limited period of time ?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a request that a vendor issue a license, and it should be addressed to the product vendor sales or support department (of which StackOverflow is neither).

Comment: Software licensing questions should be on [programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/) or [superuser](http://superuser.com/), as per [meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274963/questions-about-licensing/274964#274964)

Comment: @RJFalconer this question is a _very_ poor fit for Programmers - it would be quickly voted down and closed over there, see [Why we're not customer support for \[your favorite company\]](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/255745/839601). Recommended reading: **[What goes on Programmers.SE? A guide for Stack Overflow](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260)**

Comment: @gnat that meta post pertains to questions on SO, not Programmers. Programmers FAQ specifically lists "software licensing" as on-topic. Your link warns about questions relating to licensing legal issues, which this question isn't about either. I don't see why it would be inappropriate to port.

Comment: @RJFalconer have you read [Programmers meta guidance](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7182/31260) referred in prior comment? at Programmers it's the same as at SO, it's not a site to be used to dump customer support questions

Comment: @gnat I'm still confused. Let's discuss in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82473/programmers-on-topic-questions)

Comment: Should be closed as off-topic. Not programming but licensing discussion.

Answer (score 4):

You should go to http://www.ocean.slb.com, the Ocean website and use the Contact Us link to provide your request to Schlumberger. You use "HW" to identify your university. If it is Herriot Watt then I can tell you that in the past we gifted Ocean Developer licenses to your organization.

Comment: Thanks! I hope that your collegues will help me )